Value of $\int_{-e^{e}}^{e^{e}}\int_{-e^{e}}^{e^{e}}e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}dydx$?

Find the value of $\displaystyle \int_{-e^{e}}^{e^{e}}\int_{-e^{e}}^{e^{e}}e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}}dydx$.

While I was taking a look at social media, I saw the post saying:
$$\int_{-e^{e}}^{e^{e}}\int_{-e^{e}}^{e^{e}}e^{e_{e}}e_{e}^{e-e}e^{-e_{ee}^{\frac{e+e}{e}}-e_{e}e^{e-e}e_{e}}e^{-e_{e}}de_{ee}de_{e} = \pi$$
..in Desmos. Finally, I realized the author franked us using Desmos' recognition of $e_e$ and $e_{ee}$ as variables.
I then organized it into a simpler one, and I now have:
$$\int_{-e^e}^{e^e} \int_{-e^e}^{e^e} e^{-x^2-y^2}dydx.$$
And, I still don't know how to calculate this to $\pi$.
My first attempt was to say that $x^2+y^2=r^2, x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$ then rewrite the formula as:
$$\int_{-e^e}^{e^e} \int_{-e^e}^{e^e}e^{-r^2}d(r\sin\theta)d(r\cos\theta) \\
= -r^2 \int_{\arccos(-e^e/r)}^{\arccos(e^e/r)} \int_{\arcsin(-e^e/r)}^{\arcsin(e^e/r)} e^{-r^2}\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta^2$$
...and I'm stuck.
I am a genuine beginner in this part of math, and I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

In polar coordinates $dxdy$ become $rdrd\theta$. It is easy to integrate $re^{-r^{2}}$ with respect to $r$

There is no exact formula, but it is very close to$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2-y^2},\mathrm dx,\mathrm dy=\pi$$(The integrand is very small for values larger than $e^e$.)

@geetha290krm oh, I’ll try using polar coordinates. Thanks.

@ultralegend5385 Alright, then the value is just an approximation, right?

If you use the error function twice $$ \int_{-a}^{a}\int_{-a}^{a}e^{-x^{2}-y^{2}},dy,dx=\pi , \text{erf}(a)^2$$ If $a=e^e$ the result is $\text{erf}(a)^2=1-1.36 \times 10^{-101}$

@ClaudeLeibovici: Yes I am aware, but the OP cannot solve and get that value. And RDK: Yes, it is and the error is of the order $10^{-101}$ as Claude mentioned.

More details: $$
\int_{ - e^e }^{e^e } {\int_{ - e^e }^{e^e } {e^{ - x^2  - y^2 } dy} dx}  = \left( {\int_{ - e^e }^{e^e } {e^{ - t^2 } dt} } \right)^2  = \left( {\sqrt \pi  \operatorname{erf} (e^e )} \right)^2  = \pi\operatorname{erf} ^2 (e^e )
$$

I saw the post as well and I’m glad someone asked about it. Cheers!

@Aruralreader Yeap, same for me and that was the intention of the post author.

Claude noted
$$
\int_{-a}^a \int_{-a}^a \exp(-x^2-y^2)\;dx\;dy
= \left(\int_{-a}^a\exp(-x^2)\;dx)\right)^2
=\pi\operatorname{erf}(a)^2 .
$$
Here $\operatorname{erf}$ is the error function.
Now as $a \to \infty$,
$$
\operatorname{erf}(a) = 1-\frac{\exp(-a^2)}{a\sqrt{\pi}}
 +O\left(\frac{\exp(-a^2)}{a^3}\right) .
$$
With $a = e^e$ we have
$$
\operatorname{erf}(e^e) \approx1-\frac{\exp(-e^{2e})}{e^e\sqrt{\pi}} \approx 1-6.8\cdot 10^{-102}
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{erf}(e^e)^2 \approx 1-1.4\cdot 10^{-102} .
$$
Now the value $\pi$ may be "just an approximation", but the actual answer
$$
\pi\operatorname{erf}(e^e)^2
$$
agrees with $\pi$ to $100$ decimals.

\begin{aligned}
\int_{-e^e}^{e^e} \int_{-e^e}^{e^e} e^{-x^2-y^2} d y d x 
= & \int_{-e^e}^{e^e} e^{-x^2} d x \int_{-e^e}^ {e^e} e^{-y^2} d y \\
= & \left(\int_{-e^e}^{e^e} e^{-x^2} d x\right)^2 \\
= & \left(\left[\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \operatorname{erf}(x)\right]_{-e^2}^{e^2}\right)^2 \\
= & \frac{\pi}{4}\left[\operatorname{erf}\left(e^2\right)-\operatorname{erf}\left(-e^2\right)\right]^2 \\
= & \frac{\pi}{4}(1-(-1))^2 \\
= & \pi 
\end{aligned}

The error is $\operatorname{erf}(e^2)=1$.  They are close, but not equal.  Also, you changed $e^e$ to $e^2$.

Thank you very much for your comment!
